# How to find the size of a single index of string vector and print index if size equals a specific number?

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

I have a vector of strings and now I want to print a single index of that vector if the size of that index equals 4, for example.

```
std::vector<string> str = {"Time", "Hello", "User"};
```

I know how to iterate through the vector and print out the indices but I do not know how to get the size of, for example, the first index ("Time") which I then want to print to the console.

Just need a few hints here :)

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/ ?

Comment: That gives me the length of the full string. But how do I get the length of ONE string in the vector array of strings?

Comment: If `index` is the index of a element of `str` that you want to print the length of .... what's wrong with `std::cout << str[index].size()` or with `std::cout << str[index].length()`?

Comment: Also, take a look at `std::find_if`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Somehow str[index].size() did not work...

Comment: I tried again... and it DID work. Must have made a spelling mistake or something like that... Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [std::string::size()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) and If you are comfort with range loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> str = {"Time", "Hello", "User"};

    for (const auto &s: str)
    {
        if(s.size() == 4) 
        {
            std::cout<<s;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or an Iterator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> str = {"Time", "Hello", "User"};

    for (auto s = str.begin(); s != str.end(); s++)
    {
        if(s->size() == 4)
        {
            std::cout<<(*s);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps, Thanks.

Comment: It does! Thank you :)